# Unwrap an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have triggered an event called "search" along with an object.

```
    $(".btn-class").on("click", function() {

        var params = {
            "searchText": "sometext",
            "searchProps": ["prop1", "prop2", "prop3"]
        };

        COMP.Util.announce("search", {
            params: params
        })
    });
```

And in another class, I'm listening to this event and processing that object:

```
var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        init: function() {
            COMP.Util.listenTo("search", $.proxy(this.applySearch, this));
        },
        applySearch: function(params) {
            // do something
        }
    }
})
```

My question is when 'params' is passed to applySearch function, it becomes a wrapped object:

```
params: Object
searchProps: Array[3]
searchText: "sometext"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

If printed, I got:

params=%5Bobject+Object%5D

I want to be able to unwrap 'params' from Object as plain text, and also wonder why wrapping happens in this case

```
searchProps: Array[3]
searchText: "sometext"
__proto__: Object
```

Printed like this:
params=searchText=sometext&searchProps=prop1&searchProps=prop2&searchProps=prop3

Comment: You can't unwrap params without explicit namespacing, i.e. console.log(params.searchText + params.searchProps[0], etc); You could create a helper function to format the object as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "unwrap" the object with: `JSON.stringify(params)`

However, I think you might be confusing yourself by adding a key to your params object called params. You might want to leave that extra key out:

```
$(".btn-class").on("click", function() {

        var params = {
            "searchText": "sometext",
            "searchProps": ["prop1", "prop2", "prop3"]
        };

        COMP.Util.announce("search",params)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reuse jQuery method [param()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) which does the job for you.
It accepts as argument arrays and plain objects:

```js
var params = {
   "searchText": "sometext",
   "searchProps": ["prop1", "prop2", "prop3"]
};
var paramsEncoded = $.param( params );
alert(paramsEncoded)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```